# TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A written emit method test case in Angular now facing an issue is TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null.

Get the click event end call to emit method.
child component Html file

article.html

```
<a (click)="edit(item)" class="mat-card-title" style="cursor: pointer">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

viewArticle.spec.ts

```
 fit('emiter call', () => {
    const fixture2 = TestBed.createComponent(ArticleCarouselComponent);
    const component2 = fixture2.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component2.changeevent, 'emit');
    const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const button = nativeElement.querySelector('a');
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component2.changeevent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null

Answer (score 0):

You should mention `ElementRef` as a type for fixture:

something like this:

```
let fixture: ElementRef;
const nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
const button = nativeElement.querySelector('a');
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
fixture.nativeElement.detectChanges();
expect(component2.changeevent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you have provided is using fixture.detectChanges() which should be fixture2.detectChanges() in your case. That can be one of the issues.

```
fit('emiter call', () => {
    const fixture2 = TestBed.createComponent(ArticleCarouselComponent);
    const component2 = fixture2.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component2.changeevent, 'emit');
    const nativeElement = fixture2.nativeElement;
    const button = nativeElement.querySelector('a');
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    fixture2.detectChanges();
    expect(component2.changeevent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The other way to test events without Spying is as per following:

```
    it('should emit correct change event', () => {

    const fixture2 = TestBed.createComponent(ArticleCarouselComponent);
    const component2 = fixture2.componentInstance;

    component2.changeevent.subscribe((event: any) => {

      expect(event.data).toBe('test change event');
    });

   component2.changeevent.emit({data: 'test change event'});

   });
```

I hope this helps.